# Using Streams in MySQL with Node

Tags: mysql, node.js, stream

Following the example on [Piping results with Streams2](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#piping-results-with-streams2), I'm trying to stream results from MySQL to stdout in node.js.

Code looks like this:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM table')
      .stream()
      .pipe(process.stdout);
```

I get this error: `TypeError: invalid data`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Explanation

From this github [issue](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/741) for the project:

> `.stream()` returns stream in "objectMode". You can't pipe it to stdout or network
>   socket because "data" events have rows as payload, not Buffer chunks

### Fix

You can fix this using the [`csv-stringify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-stringify) module.

```
var stringify = require('csv-stringify');

var stringifier = stringify();


connection.query('SELECT * FROM table')
    .stream()
    .pipe(stringifier).pipe(process.stdout);
```

notice the extra `.pipe(stringifier)` before the `.pipe(process.stdout)`

Comment: The distinction between string (buffer, really) and object mode is a very important one, but often easily overlooked. Good catch here.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution now with the introduction of `pipeline`in Node v10 ([view documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/stream.html#streampipelinesource-transforms-destination-options)).

The pipeline method does several things:

1. Allows you to pipe through as many streams as you like.
2. Provides a callback once completed.
3. Importantly, it provides automatic clean up. Which is a benefit over the standard `pipe` method.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const mysql = require('mysql')
const {pipeline} = require('stream')
const stringify = require('csv-stringify')

const stringifier = stringify()
const output = fs.createWriteStream('query.csv')

const connection = mysql.createConnection(...)

const input = connection.query('SELECT * FROM table').stream()

pipeline(input, stringifier, process.stdout, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log('Output complete')
  }
}
```