# How can i stop my code from running asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

so i need to somehow make my for loop in my "readDataBase" function finish before the verifyDataInFile executes. i'm writing in node js and are getting data from an MySQL database. 
I haven't had any luck with any packages that provide any kind of "sleep" functions, setTimeOut doesn't work either, callbacks makes no sense to me.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
'use strict';

var mysql = require('mysql');
var fs = require('fs');
var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('Desktop\myOutput.txt');.


var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "1234"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");

  readDataBase();
  verifyDataInFile();
});

var readDataBase = function ()
{
    con.query("SELECT * FROM demo.users", function (err, rows, fields)
    {
        if (err) {
            return;
        } else {

            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
            {
                wstream.write(rows[i].id + "   " + rows[i].firstName + " " + rows[i].lastName + "   " + rows[i].email + "\n" + "\n");
            }


        }

    });

}

var verifyDataInFile = function ()
{
    fs.readFile('Desktop\myOutput.txt', function (err, fs) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (fs.indexOf('ut.cursus.luctus@utipsumac.org') >= 0) {
            console.log("something is here");
        } else {
            console.log("nope");
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: a stupid idea but in the worst case, call the verifydatainfile at the end but inside of readdatabase function.

Comment: doesn't help :/ same problem. i need to stop the program from running while the for loop executes somehow.

Comment: I know how js can be tricky with these kinds of stuff. I never manage to find a solid solution to this like ever. but here goes another dumb idea, make a global bool as true and make while that is true do nothing, then when your read is complete make it false to bypass the while which was already running to procede.

Comment: Don't do this, but learn how to do correct asynchronous programming. What you should be doing is not learn how to get around it, but learn how do sequential steps while staying asynchronous. Using callbacks correctly is the first step in this direction.

Comment: If you don't like that answer, the best thing you can do is work with a language that is not designed this way. This is literally how a program in node.js is supposed to work.

Comment: the global bool variable doesn't help either, seems like the code will either ignore it or go into it imediately after connecting and be stuck, no matter where i put the loop.

Comment: No of course the global bool doesn't work. If you could just set the cool to false when you were done, you could also just call your other function when you're done. There's no real fix other than embracing the async nature of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few difficult things going on here, but the real difficulty is when writing to the stream in loop it's hard to know when all the writes are done. It's possible to `pipe()` directly from the DB to the file, but I don't have anything in front of me to test on, so I won't try a half-baked attempt at that, but it's worth investigating.

In the mean time, you can still take advantage of the MySQL library's ability to return a stream on write to your file on the 'result' event. The advantage is that you will know you are finished when you hear the DB's 'end' event and can then proceed with verify:

```
var query = con.query("SELECT * FROM demo.users")

query.on('error', function(err) {
    // Handle error, an 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
})

query.on('result', function(row){
    connection.pause();
    // pause so the db waits for the write to finish
    wstream.write(rows[i].id + " ...etc", function(){
        // write has finished…on to the next row
        connection.resume();
    });
})

query.on('end', function() {
    verifyDataInFile();
});
```

There's more about the MySQL stream api here: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#streaming-query-rows

And here's a different answer with an example of streaming directly to a file with the help of csv-transform: [Using Streams in MySQL with Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013477/using-streams-in-mysql-with-node)